# Cover the surface of a polygon with rectangles

Tags: python, algorithm, computational-geometry

I am struggling with a python challenge.
I have a polygon that is defined by a list of corners. Each corner is 90 degrees.

I am trying to partition the surface of the polygon with the smallest possible number of rectangles.  How can I do it?

Example:

```
corners = [[91570, 49055],
       [91570, 48870],
       [91570, 48778],
       [91690, 48778],
       [91815, 48778],
       [91815, 48892],
       [91695, 48892],
       [91695, 48930],
       [92245, 48930],
       [92245, 48892],
       [92137, 48892],
       [92137, 48778],
       [92370, 48778],
       [92370, 49055]]
```

polygon:

[image]

I think the result should have around 5 rectangles.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am not sure but maybe line sweep algorithm can help

Comment: Your polygon is missing one edge in the picture!!

Comment: A note about vocabulary: in algorithm problems, the word "cover" usually implies that you're allowing overlap. So in your case if you're not allowing overlapping rectangles, I suggest editing your question to specify so. For instance you could say "partition into rectangles" instead of "cover with rectangles". Or you could add "non-overlapping" explicitly.

Comment: *"I think the result should have around 5 rectangles."* << What makes you think that? If you can explain why you think that, then you're already half-way towards solving this problem.

Comment: I think the the `minimum dissection into rectangles of a rectilinear polygon` algorithm in the suggested question solves my problem. I need to double check.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea for how I would solve this, I'm not sure if it will be fast enough, but it's something you should be able to try.

## SubProblem:

Given a polygon, find a rectangle that overlaps the polygon without any extra area (part of the rectangle outside of the polygon).

You should be able to get all the pairs of non-adjacent points, then check for whether or not the rectangle the two points make overlap the original polygon.

Now you can take this new rectangle, add it to a list of results and do a [Boolean Subtract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons) on the original polygon.

You can repeat this until there are no points left.

## Optimizations

If you are sure the output size is small, then this shouldn't be too bad if you want to just brute force it. If you have `n` points, then the number of possible rectangles you can choose is `O(n^2)`. In the worst case, you only remove 3 points at a time, which means the worst-case number of rectangles you can have in your output is roughly `n/3`, making the total time complexity of brute-force `O(n^3)`.

As for how to choose which rectangle to take, I'm not the best at optimization problems, so from here I'll leave it to you, but I have a few ideas:

1. Dynamic programming.
2. Greedy, just choose the biggest rectangle.
3. Genetic algorithm.